# Star pyramid with while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I am currently puzzled on making a star pyramid.
My product needs to be able to create a pyramid with a user-inputted # of rows. So if I say 3, the pyramid would look like:

```
  *
 ***
*****
```

When I enter 3, my pyramid (based on my code below) looks like:

```
   *
   ***
   *****
```

I'm having trouble making the spaces get deducted when going down a row. I seem to have other parts down accurately, so my question is, **how do I deduct spaces for each following row by 1 after the initial amount of spaces? Could I get help on how to fix my code?** (while using a while loop). Feel free to comment on any other parts of my code if it seems inaccurate though.

At the moment this is what my code looks like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AstPyramid{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("How tall do you want your pyramid to be? Rows: ");
       int rowCounter = keyboard.nextInt();     
       int baseLength = 1;
       int starsInRow = 1;

       while (baseLength <= rowCounter){
         int starCounter = 1;
         int whiteSpace = rowCounter/2; 

         while (whiteSpace >= 0){
            System.out.print(" ");
            whiteSpace--;
         }         

         while (starCounter <= starsInRow){
            System.out.print("*");
            starCounter++;
         }

            System.out.println();
            baseLength++;
            starsInRow=starsInRow+2;    
       }
    }
}
```

Update: I updated this question many times and already have received an answer pertaining to it. Could this question be un-held now? I'm not sure if editing this post notifies anybody, but it is worth another try.

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't understand _how_ this is off-topic.

Comment: @ShashwatBlack not sure either, but I edited my topic post and put the primary question in bold font. Tried to make it more concise, too. For now I'm just following Textant's advice. So thankful somebody answered before this question became on hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the first inner-loop that you are using to print the white space, always runs for `rowCounter / 2` times. That is the problem. It should ideally start at that value, and keep decreasing for each iteration of the outer loop.

You could have a `spacesPerRow` variable and assign it an initial value of `rowCounter / 2`, outside the outer loop. Then on each outer-loop iteration, you can decrease it. And use this `spacesPerRow` in your first inner loop to print the spaces.

Your `spacesPerRow` should be decremented once for each iteration of the outer loop. An ideal place would be right after your first inner loop finishes.

---

**To moderators & question down-voters:**

I can't add comments, so I'll add my thoughts here. The first few lines of the question precisely mention the problem: "I want to do X, but my code is doing Y". And the OP is not able to figure out why.

I also believe the code doesn't include a lot of unnecessary parts either.

I am wondering why this is considered off-topic, put on hold, and has two down-votes.

Comment: I was able to set an initial value for spaceCounter which worked how it should, but now I'm just wondering how to decrement the spaceCounter by 1 for each iteration. My question is: where do I put the "spaceCounter--;"? I would think it'd go in the first while statement like my original code, although that doesn't seem to decrement anything. Or is it that the problem is possibly in the while (statement) itself?

Comment: I understand why the spaceCounter--; would go into the inner loop (with the while statement) because that would order to limit the amount of times the spaces are looped, although something is still wrong. I completely updated my first post so I hope you have time to spare another look. Thank you for the advice thus far, even though this question is still on hold.

Comment: This URL has a modified version of your code: http://ideone.com/dCr1CW - I've added comments explaining what we're doing there & why it works.

Comment: Also, please revert your question to have the original source code, or others might not get the context of what we're discussing here.